# Is it worth posting reproducibility studies

Tags: reproducible-research

As an undergraduate interested in Academia, is it worth posting your reproducibility study of a paper on arXiv and linking to it on Google scholar? Is it useful to future graduate schools? Specifically with regards Machine Learning and Computer Science..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, publishing reproducibility studies is encouraged:

- It helps the research community determine whether the original study is valid and reliable.
- It helps other researchers or students reproduce the study themselves, in particular in order [to improve or build upon it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants).
- It benefits your reputation: people might cite it, and it will be taken into account when you apply for a position or a grant later.
- Some conferences/journals in ML encourage submitting reproducibility studies, so you might even be able to get a peer-reviewed publication out if it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definitely valuable and helps validate existing research to publish reproductions of existing results. In addition to publishing them on arXiv you might also want to consider submitting them to [ReScience](https://rescience.github.io/) (if they are computational studies). 
ReScience reviews the reproductions through a very open and transparent review process.